# Unclear step in computation of a marginal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

[image]

Above is a screenshot (from [this page](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~stephentu/writeups/dirichlet-conjugate-prior.pdf)) that is showing how to compute the probability of the observed data given a Dirichlet prior. I don't see how they got from the expression in blue to the one in red. Isn't that a multinomial expression that requires a term that specifies how many ways you can observe that data? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unary representation, or creation of "dummy variables",  seems to reflect the passage that you showed in your example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)

I'm assuming that $y_i$ ranges from 1 to k. The probability that $y_i=j$ equals $p_j$.

The passage that you emphasized there corresponds to the categorical distribution

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution

and the Dirichlet is the conjugate to the categorial distribution

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

In your question, the Dirichlet distribution appears in the term in the left just before the one that you marked in red.